# Is it possible to limit the number of rows returned by SQL Server Management Studio in 100s of servers at once?

Tags: sql-server

There are more than 100 of servers that we're administering. In each of them when we type

```
select * from tbl_name
```

All rows are returned unlike 1000 rows in sqlyog.

Is there an easy way to configure 100s of servers at once to limit the number of rows returned to 1000?

The problem with this is that sometimes the server goes down because someone forgets `top 1000` in his sql code.

Comment: The actual answer to this question is to disable the login of anyone who forgets the `top 1000` - without exception. Loss of access is a great motivator to do things correctly.

Comment: lol that's what they did and one guy  left the job bcoz of that humiliation.

Answer (score 6):

> The problem with this is that sometimes the server goes down because someone forgets `top 1000` in his sql code.

Honestly, this is a process issue, not one that can be solved technologically. It is important to be conscious of writing performant SQL and that only those who should have open access to do so, do.

I say this because even always using `TOP 1000` doesn't protect you from overloading the server. `TOP` is generally a late stage operator in the query plan, but depending on how the rest of the query is written and how the tables are architected and indexed, it's still possible to get table scan operations against large tables. This would effectively result in the majority of the work still occuring on your server, causing resource contention, only to throw away most of the rows it doesn't need once the `TOP` operation processes at the end of execution.

> Is it possible to limit the number of rows returned by SQL Server Management Studio in 100s of servers at once?

Perhaps [`SET ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) could help you:

> Causes SQL Server to stop processing the query after the specified number of rows are returned.

You can use it in your SQL queries but you'd have to remember to write it just the same as `TOP`. Otherwise, it sounds like SSMS might have this as a setting under `Query execution > SQL Server > Set rowcount` but you'll need to remember to set this on everyone's SSMS client (including when new people are hired), and it'll only help you for those SSMS clients. Someone could theoretically still execute poor SQL while testing new application code, for example. This is why it's utmost important to fix the process and make people be responsible for the code they write.